# Does ArrayList.clear() resize the array to the smallest possible size?

Tags: java, arraylist

If I understand ArrayLists, they're backed by an array which is automatically resized when its full.
On calling clear() is the ArrayList resized to the smallest possible array size?

Comment: Just look into the source code...

Comment: I did. A for loop iterates through the ArrayList setting objects to null. But that doesn't answer my question.

Comment: No, but `ArrayList.trimToSize` does. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#trimToSize%28%29

Comment: Thanks Greg, that method will work.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No it's not, and this is an issue to keep in mind. Assuming ArrayList's internal Object[] grew up to 1000000 elements. Now you call ArrayList.clear(). This sets all 1000000 elements to null and internal size to 0. Nulling 1000000 is a time expensive operation and ArrayList will still occupy 1000000 x 4 bytes Object[] on the heap. You can call ArrayList.trimToSize() after clear() but there's a catch - you first cleared 1000000 elements then threw them away. In this situation a much better solution is to just recreate your ArrayList - new ArrayList().

Answer (score 2):

**The size is set to 0 but there's no resize that happens explicitly** 
Here's the actual code.

```
     public void  clear() {
         modCount++;
         // Let gc do its work
         for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
             elementData[i] = null;
         size = 0;
     }
```

Please check this [link](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/ArrayList.java#ArrayList.clear%28%29).

Comment: So the array is not resized. `size` is just the number of used array elements.

Answer (score 0):

The size is set to zero. `arrayList.clear()` sets all the objects contained in an arraylist to null. But this does not ensure that all the objects contained in the arraylist will be garbage collected.The objects which have references elsewhere will not be Garbage collected till all references are removed.

Comment: Strictly speaking, the objects will be garbage collected when they become _unreachable_.

Answer (score 0):

to reduce the size you need to use trimToSize () potentially after clearing it. generally this isn't done as it doesn't make much difference unless you array looking to save many MB.  A more common solution is to replace the ArrayList in that situation. (I am not saying that is better)